# #2002 - El servidor no está respondiendo (o el zócalo local al servidor MySQL no está configurado correctamente)

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, phpmyadmin

Verán tengo una base de datos en `phpmyadmin` y al querer hacer una consulta a una tabla, no me deja, sólo puedo visualizarla pero no puedo hacer consultas, cuando intento hacer mi propia consulta, en SQL me aparece:

> 2002 - El servidor no está respondiendo (o el zócalo local al servidor MySQL no está configurado correctamente).

Pero sólo eso, las demás tablas que tengo en esa base de datos sí tengo acceso a ellas y sí puedo hacer consultas.

PD. Estoy en `windows` y no utilizo xampp

Comment: Creo que es porque tienes un programa anti malwares activado y no te deja conectar prueba desconectandolo temporalmente.

Comment: No te conectes por socket. Usa TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Este error es debido a que la configuración de tu phpMyAdmin tiene la ruta equivocada al `mysql.sock`. Esto lo encuentras en el archivo `config.inc.php`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock';
```

Lo que me parece extraño es que si te funcione para otras tablas. Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Comenta que está en windows... así que no creo que que el socket se encuentre en '/var/lib.....'

Comment: Para ver el socket en windows: ve al panel de xampp, click en `Config` en la parte de `MySQL`. Click en `my.ini`. Justo abajo te muestra: `socket          = "D:/Xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"`, esa es la dirección del socket en mi ordenador, en el tuyo será diferente.

Answer (score 1):

yo resolví el problema en `config.inc.php,` estableciendo el puerto actual de conexión por defecto en la **ip**. el cual había cambiado anteriormente para utilizar otro programa en local al mismo tiempo

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307' 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3306'
```

El ultimo es el que me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso era por el firewall.

1. He añadido una regla en `"Inbound Rules"` con el puerto que usa **MySql**.

Ya funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

tenía el mismo problema y lo resolví indicando el puerto por defecto tanto para MySQL como para MariaDB tal cual como indica "FRANCISCO J. BLANCO"

Comment: Cambiar esto y listo:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3306';

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega todo en la respuesta. de paso mira [answer]

Answer (score -3):

Siga estos pasos:

1. Desinstale wamp
2. Instale los 3 paquetes de Visual Basic 2012, 13 y 15 ([enlace](https://www.microsoft.com/es-co/download/details.aspx?id=40784))
3. Vuelva a instalar wamp

Comment: Hola Edward, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad, por favor, intenta editarla siguiendo los consejos que se encuentran en [ask] (p.e. añadiendo una descripción de por qué esos pasos solucionarán el problema). También te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: esto que tiene que ver con mysql? podrias explicarlo?