# error al entrar en mysql con XAMPP 3.2.2

Tags: mysql

hola a todos tengo me estoy encontrando con el siguiente problema

al intentar ingresar al servidor de phpmyadmin en mi local host me manda el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi config.inc.php

```html
/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

Comment: intenta iniciar xampp como administrador... yo tenia el mismo problema y lo solucione asi e instalando el servicio (mysql)

Comment: EL error es obvio te está pidiendo password y no loppnes

Comment: ademas no creo que instales mysql sin claves

Comment: El usuario root de mysql tiene un password por default definido??

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

**Desde una consola de mySQL:**

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('nuevoPassWord') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

[Ver guia para utilizar la consola de mysql desde windows](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/2408.php)

**En tu archivo  config.inc.php modifica la siguiente linea**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

**Por esta:**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'nuevoPassWord';
```

**Reinicia el xampp y vuelve a iniciarlo.**

Comment: ahora me marca otro error  Error
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#2002 -  — El servidor no está respondiendo (o el zócalo local al servidor MySQL no está configurado correctamente).
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n.
 La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n.

Comment: Entonces has solucionado el error de clave, ahora el error es otro: en base al error puedes solucionarlo utilizando la solución planteada en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14866/2002-el-servidor-no-est%C3%A1-respondiendo-o-el-z%C3%B3calo-local-al-servidor-mysql-no